# PowerBi: Extract month from dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss issue

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to extract month from  **CreateDate** field whose values are in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format.

Expecting **Nov**  to be present for the all 4 rows in the Column field but power bi considers date number as the month field and gives the incorrect values

[image]

Comment: Your assumption of format being `dmy` is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format of your **Createdate** is *English (United States)* while you expect it to be *English (United Kingdom)*. The type conversion should've been done properly in the PowerQuery editor **"Using locale ..."***

[image]

[image]